# Trying to get the current user ID in Box API v2 for Android

Tags: android, box-api

Hello I`m trying to get the current user information using the BoxAndroidLibrarV2 methods but I get null pointer every time, I tried with getId getLogin but my app crash every time. Here is the method I´m using.

---

Forget it I recreate the calling methods I used.

Answer (score 0):

You should just call [GET /users/me](http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-get-the-current-users-information).  It gives you the basic user profile.  If you want extra fields, see the [documentation](http://developers.box.com/docs/#fields) on how to request specific fields.